# ValueError and ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, valueerror

I'm trying to perform a calculation ((x/y) + z) and account for 2 errors: `ValueError` and `ZeroDivisionError.`

However, I'm having difficulty understanding how to code these 2 errors into my program. I think I have `ValueError` figured out, but not `ZeroDivisionError`. Here's what I have so far. Sorry it's messy rn....

```
user_input = (input("Enter three numbers separated by a space: ")).split()
x = int(user_input[0])
y = int(user_input[1])
z = int(user_input[2])
  
def calculate(x, y, z):
    '''calculate (x/y)+z'''
    c = ((x/y) + z) if y != 0 else print("Second input value cannot be 0")
    return c

try:
    input_values_str = str(user_input)
    c = ((x/y) + z)
    for val in input_values_str:
        if len(user_input) == 3:
            print("Correct number of values.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect number of values entered.")

except ValueError:
    print(user_input," is not valid input.")

except ZeroDivisionError:
    y = 0
    print("Second value cannot be 0")
print("Formula: ({}/{}) + {} = {}".format(x, y, z, calculate(x, y, z)))
```

Comment: Are there any particular problems you encounter when running your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats on learning Python! I think your code is a bit confused. I'm gonna post your version with some of my comments and then I'll post a cleaned up version that I think better achieves what you're trying to do. Hopefully it's instructional. There are more elegant ways of doing this, but I'm trying to retain your structure as much makes sense.

**Your Code:**

```
user_input = (input("Enter three numbers separated by a space: ")).split()
x = int(user_input[0])
y = int(user_input[1])
z = int(user_input[2])

def calculate(x, y, z):
    c = ((x/y) + z) if y != 0 else print("Second input value cannot be 0")  #Why do you need a ZeroDivisonError check below when you check for Zero here?
return c

try:
    input_values_str = str(user_input) # why are you taking an input here? Did you take the input above? And why convert it back into a string?
    c = ((x/y) + z)
    for val in input_values_str: # Why are you iterating through string? You're basically checking 3 times if the length of your string is 3 characters
        if len(user_input) == 3:
            print("Correct number of values.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect number of values entered.")

except ValueError:
    print(user_input," is not valid input.")

except ZeroDivisionError:
    y = 0 # why set y back to zero in the event oa ZeroDivisonError? Won't that just create a ZeroDivison Error? Might make more sense to get a new input from the user
    print("Second value cannot be 0")
print("Formula: ({}/{}) + {} = {}".format(x, y, z, calculate(x, y, z))) # if the objective is to only print something, why not do it in the calculate function? Then we can contain your ZeroDivisionError in their and request a new y
```

**My Code:**

```
def calculate(x, y, z):
    try:
        solution = (x/y) + z
        print(f"Formula: ({x}/{y}) + {z} = {solution}")

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        y = int(input("2nd value cannot be a Zero. Please input a new y value: "))
        calculate(x, y, z)

try:
    user_input = (input("Enter three numbers separated by a space: ")).split()

    while len(user_input) != 3:
        print("Incorrect number of values entered.")
        user_input = (input("Enter three numbers separated by a space: ")).split()

    x = int(user_input[0])
    y = int(user_input[1])
    z = int(user_input[2])

    calculate(x, y, z)

except ValueError:
    print(user_input," is not valid input.")
```

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification. I only had the if y !=... and ZeroDivisionError both in there because I was trying both methods.  I asked for input in the try loop because I thought that's what my textbook was telling me to do. I also didn't realize that I was iterating through the string so many times. And lastly, I was again following this textbook I have...guess it's explanations aren't very clear.

Comment: Been there man. The more you code, the better you get!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need the try/except/except block at all.  You're already checking for `y=0` in your `calculate` method, and you already know you have valid input or the `split` and casts `int()` would have failed.  The `for` loop in there prints the same output string over and over.  If you take all that out, your code seems to work fine

```
try:
    file_name = open('/tmp/data.txt', 'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File could not be found. Please check spelling of file name!")
    sys.exit()

#Read lines in file
Lines = file_name.read().splitlines()

user_input = (input("Enter three numbers separated by a space: ")).split()
x = int(user_input[0])
y = int(user_input[1])
z = int(user_input[2])

def calculate(x, y, z):
    '''calculate (x/y)+z'''
    c = ((x / y) + z) if y != 0 else print("Second input value cannot be 0")
    return c

print("Formula: ({}/{}) + {} = {}".format(x, y, z, calculate(x, y, z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You raised an exception to look if y == 0 but the first value (x) can not be 0 either. And you need to put the 2 if statements before the c = ...

Try this:

```
user_input = (input("Enter three numbers separated by a space: ")).split()
x = int(user_input[0])
y = int(user_input[1])
z = int(user_input[2])

def calculate(x, y, z):
    '''calculate (x/y)+z'''
    if y == 0 or x == y:
        print("Invalid Input")
    else:
        c = ((x/y) + z)
        return c

try:
    input_values_str = str(user_input)
    c = ((x/y) + z)
    for val in input_values_str:
        if len(user_input) == 3:
            print("Correct number of values.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect number of values entered.")

except ValueError:
    print(user_input," is not valid input.")

except ZeroDivisionError:
    y = 0
    x = 0
    print("Second value cannot be 0. First Value cannot be 0")
    print("Formula: ({}/{}) + {} = {}".format(x, y, z, calculate(x, y, z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tweaked your code to meet the expectation of yours, and easy to understand.

```
user_input = (input("Enter three numbers separated by a space: ")).split()
x = int(user_input[0])
y = int(user_input[1])
z = int(user_input[2])

try:
    c = ((x/y) + z) if y != 0 else print("Second input value cannot be 0")
except ValueError:
    print(user_input," is not valid input.")
print("Formula: ({}/{}) + {} = {}".format(x, y, z, c))
```